# Condesing and deleting information from an Excel macros

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with a VB macro.  Essentially what I am trying to do is for the macros to read the input and first determine whether or not a cells ID number matches the one in the row.  Example: If row 1 has an ID of 1122 and rows 2,3,4 and 5 all match, I want the macro to read that and create a count in the NbrOfA cell.  Once it realizes that there is not an ID match it moves on to the next ID and looks for matches of that ID number and continues to create a count. While it is doing this, I also need it to read from another column that has specific strings such as "open", "closed" ect. read that input, and create a separate row titled NbrofOpenA.  Once it runs out of data, I then want to have a singular cell that shows the number of actions (NbrOfA) that match the ID number as well as the number of open actions (NbrOfOpenA).

Currently I receive the error: “compile error: sub or function not defined” highlighting the Set Cell(Sheet2.Cells(FirstRowOfI, 23) = NbrOfA

Attached in the excel sheet attached it shows 2 cells deleted. They will not actually be deleted, just wanted to give an idea of what I was looking for

```
Sub ACount()
Dim FirstRowofI
Dim NbrOfA as Integer
Dim NbrOfOpenA as Integer
Row = 2

Set FirstRowofI = (Sheet2.Cells.Range(Row, 14))
NbrOfA = 0
NbrOfOpenA = 0
    If (Sheet2.Cells(Row, 14).Value <> "") Then
        NbrOfA = 1
    If (Sheet2.Cells(Row, 22) <> "Closed") Then
        NbrOfOpenA = 1
Set Row = FirstRowofI
Row = Row + 1

Do While (Sheet2.Cells(Row, 14) = (Sheet2.Cells(FirstRowofI, 14)))
    NbrOfOpenA = NbrOfOpenA + 1
    If (Sheet2.Cells(Row, 22) <> "Closed" Then
        NbrOfOpenA = NbrOfOpenA + 1
        Range(Row).EntireRow.Delete
    Return
    End If
Set Cell(Sheet2.Cells(FirstRowofI, 23)) = NbrOfA
Set Cell(Sheet2.Cells(FirstRowofI, 24)) = NbrOfOpenA

Loop

End Sub
```

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6RWe.png)

Comment: Maybe I haven't read it correctly but I can't find where your run into any problems with your code. What doesn't work right now?

Comment: Alex. I will edit my post. Currently I receive a “compile error: sub or function not defined” highlighting the Set Cell(Sheet2.Cells(FirstRowOfI, 23) = NbrOfA

Comment: You have a number of syntax issues going on here - firstly, put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module and declare everything. You can't `Set` an `Integer` - just write `FirstRowofI = Sheet2.Cells(Row, 14)`. Your first couple `If` statements need to be closed with an `End If`, but it looks like you also need an `ElseIf` in there.

Comment: In my opinion, you need to scratch this whole thing and start over - almost every line of this has a syntax error. You need to start off with something very simple first, utilizing `Debug.Print` to make sure you're iterating through the right rows, then build from there. You're better off starting over than trying to fix this mess, no offense.

Comment: No offense taken. Honestly I’m brand new to VBA and this was code I was given and I attempted to modify it. I wasn’t sure if it were possible and I continued to have errors when I ran it!

Comment: @jsiegz26 Whoever gave you this code mustn't have been able to run it either... do you have the original, unedited code? Also please give a better before/example picture - you want to completely remove your first table and replace it with the below table? Where are the destination cells - include the row numbers and column letters in your screenshot.

Comment: The destination cells are another portion of the macro. It’s populating information that is produced through a 3rd party program. The portion of code that brings it from one sheet to another I have done and know how to do that. It’s mainly just getting a count and then deleting the cells that match. I understand how confusing this is and am trying to gain more information from the other person I’m working on this with.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need VBA? You can easily achieve what you're looking for with formulas, heck even a Pivot Table! Here's an example with formulas:

[image: img1]

Comment: unfortunately I do since the macro is population information from a different source and will continue to change each time the information is updated.